# Nexus--How to separate artifact upload?

Tags: maven, maven-2, nexus

Recently,Our Team are using Nexus to manager Maven repositories.We want to separate user to different authority,like user no one can upload artifact to 3rd Party,can not upload to Release.(Both 3rd Party and Release type are hosted)
Is there any possibility to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can assign different rights in the Security->Users area (at least in Nexus professional). You need to define a suitable role and assign it to the user.